# C# MVC View Model return IEnumerable list using join table

Tags: c#, linq, model-view-controller

As I work on my project and learn from each step I still get stuck on some parts. I have 3 tables SubJobs, MaterialRequired, and Parts. Material required is really only a referance table. What I need to produce in my view is the SubJob Detail and then a list of parts. So a Subjob has many parts and I wanted to keep the Parts table clean without having to add duplicate data in the parts table. For instance SubJob number 102311 may have the part number Ef3012 and another SubJob may have the same part. So I dont want to have the same part number 5 times in the table with different SubJobs. So I made a MaterialRequired Table that holds the SubJob number and the PartNumber both are keys for the other tables. I am feeding the page a SubJob number and display the data in a ViewModel. The page loads with the SubJob detail but I am having issues with displaying the parts. In the below code result.RequiredDetail produces a list of partNumbers from the MaterialsRequired as it should. I am only using this code to find out how it works. The result.PartsDetail in its current form only produces 1 record instead of all for that subjob. Is there something I am missing in the model itself or is there another way to do the result to get the list I need?

Here is my ViewModel:

```
    public partial class SubJobDetails
{
    public static SubJobDetails GetSubjobsAndParts(string mReq, CustomerEntities db)
    {
        var Parts = from pts in db.Parts
                   join mr in db.MaterialRequired on pts.PartNumber equals mr.Material
                   join sj in db.SubJobs on mr.SubJob equals sj.JobNumber
                   where (mr.SubJob == mReq)
                   select new SubJobDetails()
                   {
                       Parts = pts,
                       Material = mr,
                       SubJobs = sj
                   };

        var result = Parts.FirstOrDefault();

        if (result != null)
        {
            result.RequiredDetail = db.MaterialRequired.Where(a => a.SubJob == result.SubJobs.JobNumber);
            result.PartsDetail = db.Parts.Where(a => a.PartNumber == result.Material.Material);
        };

        return result;
    }

    public virtual Parts Parts { get; set; }
    public virtual SubJobs SubJobs { get; set; }
    public virtual MaterialRequired Material { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Parts> PartsDetail { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<MaterialRequired> RequiredDetail { get; set; }
```

This is the controller (I believe it is working as expected):

```
        public ActionResult PartsDetail(string mReq)
    {
        if (mReq == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        SubJobDetails modelInstance = SubJobDetails.GetSubjobsAndParts(mReq, db);
        //if (modelInstance == null)
        //{
        //    return HttpNotFound();
        //}
        return View(modelInstance);
```

Here is my view page:

```
@model BestenEquipment.Models.SubJobDetails
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "PartsDetail";
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/CustomerDashboardLayout.cshtml";
}

<div id="page-wrapper">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div>
            <h4>Sub Job</h4>
            <hr />
            <dl class="dl-horizontal">

                <dt>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SubJobs.Description)
                </dt>

                <dd>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SubJobs.Description)
                </dd>

                <dt>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SubJobs.ExtDescription)
                </dt>

                <dd>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SubJobs.ExtDescription)
                </dd>

                <dt>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SubJobs.PartNumber)
                </dt>

                <dd>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SubJobs.PartNumber)
                </dd>

                <dt>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SubJobs.Drawing)
                </dt>

                <dd>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SubJobs.Drawing)
                </dd>
            </dl>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div>
                    <h4>Parts</h4>
                    <table class="table">
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Parts.PartNumber)
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Parts.Description)
                            </th>

                            <th>
                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Parts.ExtDescription)
                            </th>

                            <th>
                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Parts.DrawingNumber)
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        @foreach (var item in Model.PartsDetail)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.PartNumber)
                                </td>

                                <td>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Description)
                                </td>

                                <td>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.ExtDescription)
                                </td>

                                <td>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.DrawingNumber)
                                </td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution to the issue above. First I took the MaterialsRequired and Parts and made a SQL View. created a model called PartsView "Also the name of the SQL View" I only needed to make 1 join at this point but I did add another join to this to give me the button link back to the Top level Job "MachineDetail" page.

Here is the ViewModel:

```
    public partial class SubJobDetails
{
    public static SubJobDetails GetSubjobsAndParts(string mReq, CustomerEntities db)
    {

        var Parts = from pts in db.PartsView
                    join sj in db.SubJobs on pts.SubJob equals sj.SubJob
                    join tlj in db.TopLvlJobs on sj.TopLvlJob equals tlj.TopLvlJob
                    where (pts.SubJob == mReq)
                   select new SubJobDetails()
                   {
                       PartsView = pts,
                       TopLvlJob = tlj.TopLvlJob,
                       SubJobs = sj,

                   };

        var result = Parts.FirstOrDefault();

        if (result != null)
        {
            result.PartsDetail = db.PartsView.Where(a => a.SubJob == result.PartsView.SubJob);
        };

        return result;
    }
    public string TopLvlJob { get; set; }
    public virtual TopLvlJobs TopLvlJobs { get; set; }
    public virtual PartsView PartsView { get; set; }
    public virtual SubJobs SubJobs { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<PartsView> PartsDetail { get; set; }
}
```

The Controller Action stayed the same. The razor page stayed the same only adding an "if" statement in the foreach to only show records where IsViewable = true.